# Show Different category name in tooltip in spotfire bar chart

Tags: tibco, spotfire

We have a requirement for showing ID in category axis and description of same ID in tooltip.

I have multiple columns in my data like value 1 ,value2,value 3 etc. value 1, value 2 are columns.

I am putting this on **value axis** as an expression like `Sum([value 1]) as [AC 6076 ], Sum([Value 2]) as [AC 6078 ]`, etc. that is this will hardcoded as IDs in category axis

So my **category axis** is column names. that is *<[Axis.Default.Names]>*  .

please see the attached picture. It's the description against a column not a row.

It would be an expression in tooltip which may be something like

```
First(Case when '${Axis.Y.DisplayName}'='AC 6076' then "description 1"   when '${Axis.Y.DisplayName}'='AC 6078 ' then "description 2"  else  " Description 3" end )
```

This expression is not showing correct value. it wil always show "Descrition 3"

i want to show this IDs(column names in category axis) and a description for each of these column names in tooltip. please have a look at the picture attached.

[Atatched picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbSwr.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
First(CASE 
    WHEN '${Axis.Y.DisplayName}'='AC 6076' THEN "description 1"
    WHEN '${Axis.Y.DisplayName}'='AC 6078 ' THEN "description 2"
    ELSE  " Description 3" 
  END)
```

this always evaluates to your ELSE condition because `${Axis.Y.DisplayName}` will always be the full display name for the axis, not the individual columns (i.e., `"AC 6076, AC 6078"`).

you will need to add your description text to your data somehow. this is a little convoluted and will require some tweaking on your end, but the principle is the same.

this is assuming your table is something like this:

```
key   val1  val2
a     1     4
b     2     5
c     3     6
```

1. from the menu, select **File..Add Data Tables...**
2. click **Add** then select the data table powering your visualization from the **From Current Analysis** heading
3. expand the Transformations pane at the bottom of this dialog
4. choose a **Pivot** transform and click **Add...*
5. leave everything default except for **Transfer columns...**, where you should add only the columns you wish to sum (e.g., `[value 1]` and `[value 2]`)
6. **OPTIONALLY** change the naming scheme to just `%T`
7. click **OK**

your table now looks like (ignoring optional steps):

```
Sum(val1)  Sum(val2)
6          15
```

8. choose another transform, this time **Unpivot**, and click **Add...*
9. add all columns to **Columns to transform**
10. click **OK**

now you have:

```
Category   Value
Sum(val1)  6
Sum(val2)  15
```

11. choose one last transform: **Calculate new column** and click **Add...*
12. enter your case statement that will determine the description and name the column "Description" or something
13. click **OK**
14. click **OK**

your final table will resemble:

```
Category   Value   Description
Sum(val1)  6       This is the sum of value 1
Sum(val2)  15      This is the sum of value 2
```

15. on your bar chart, the category axis expression should be `Category` and value should be `Sum(Value)` (assuming you didn't change the column names in step 9)
16. add a new line to the tooltip with an expression `First([Description])`, or whatever you named the new column in step 12

whew. it's a lot of steps but it works. the goal is to get the description data into it's own column so you can put it in the tooltip. since your data is aggregated and doesn't exist in its own column, this is the only way I can think of doing it.

Comment: Hi Niko
Thanks for this.

Comment: Hi Niko thanks
But i cant unpivot my table as i have around 40 value columns. so if i upivot i will have a huge redundant data.

Comment: So i was wondering if there is any way to do this without unpivoting.thats why i posted this question here

Comment: unfortunately I don't think there is an elegant solution to this, but maybe someone else will have some input. I don't understand the redundant info, though. remember, this is a **new** data table referencing your original one; you are not transforming your original data table. you will wind up with a new table with three columns: `[Category]` (containing the aggregate column name e.g., `Sum([value 1])`), `[value]` (containing the value of the aggregate), and `[Description]` (containing your description. I'll add some sample info to my answer above to clarify.

Comment: My data have almost 20 lakhs of rows.which will increase in future.So even if i unpivot this data by transforming new data table will have around 20*40 lakhs or rows. So i think it will reduce the performance ?

Comment: I don't think you will have much issue with performance, especially if you're running this on a Spotfire Server with adequate resources. 800 rows (not sure what lahks are?) isn't nearly enough to take a performance hit. even if you had many thousands, performance shouldn't suffer much since the initial pivot is a very simple one and all transforms after that don't really do any calculation. there will likely be manual work if you add new categories to your data, however.

Comment: your best bet is to try it and see. I don't know how your environment is configured nor the extent of your dataset, and even if I did the best way to find out is, well, to just find out! :)

Comment: you maybe can try to get your data into spotfire in a different format. if this is coming from a database, you can adjust your query in the information link to pivot it before it's added to the analysis. this might be a way around the manual steps when new categories are added.

Comment: Thanks Niko. I mean 2 million rows. so if I pivot it,it will be around 2*40 =80million rows.Anyways, I will check the performance. So is it almost sure that we can't do this without unpivot?Much appreciated

Comment: I think we're miscommunicating. it's just a `Sum([column])`, so if you can do this operation inside a bar chart with no performance hit, you can certainly do the same inside of a pivot transformation. you are not pivoting in a traditional sense; it's more of a summary table. I thought you meant you would have 800 CATEGORIES (like your "AC 6078"s) in which case... well you'll have trouble no matter what you try to do.